# Changing logger for Exception thrown by WebMethod

Tags: log4j, wildfly

I have a webservice project running as .ear in a Wilffly 8. This web service should have it's own logfile, which I defined in the log4j properties. This works fine for log calls from inside the project.

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("myLogger");

@WebMethod
public void doSomething() {
    try {
        foo();
    } catch (MyException e) {
        // This goes to the log file specified in root logger
        logger.error("Oh noes!", e);
    }
}
```

However, if the WebMethod throws an exception itself, it goes to the Wildfly log.

```
@WebMethod
public void doSomething() throws MyException {
    // When MyException is thrown, it goes to Wildfly log instead of my specified log
    foo();
}
```

Is there a way to write that exception to my custom log file too? I already thought of doing it manually like this:

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("myLogger");

@WebMethod
public void doSomething() throws MyException {
    try {
        foo();
    } catch (MyException e) {
        logger.error("Oh noes!", e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

But this way it would end up in both logs and I'd also like to keep it out of the Wildfly log.

Comment: I think this is probably a bug. Do you just include a log4j.properties file and allow the server to configure the log manager?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Yes, my ear project has it's own log4j.xml. From what I read this is the proper (easy) way to override Wildfly default logging per deployment. A described this works fine for explicit `Logger` calls.